# Angular wrong validation in checkbox type

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have a form with some types of inputs. There is a mistake in validation in the `checkbox` type. See the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2oj6o6) demo.

First, check the first item. Then check the second one and then uncheck the first one. It shows **error message**!

Html:

```html
<form name="form" (ngSubmit)="addBookletForm.valid && addBooklet()" #addBookletForm="ngForm" novalidate >
  <label *ngFor="let option of levelCheckboxes">
    <div *ngIf="( booklet_level.touched || addBookletForm.submitted) && booklet_level.invalid && booklet_level.errors.required">
        <div class="saz-alert saz-alert-red saz-alert-small saz-color-red" *ngIf="booklet_level.errors.required">
          This is required!
        </div>
    </div>
    <input name="booklet_level" #booklet_level="ngModel" required value="{{option.value}}" [(ngModel)]="option.checked" type="checkbox">
    {{option.name}}

  </label>
</form>
```

Typescript:

```js
levelCheckboxes = [
    { name:'one', value:'1', checked:false },
    { name:'two', value:'2', checked:false },
    { name:'three', value:'3', checked:false }
]
```

Comment: Apparently, all of the radio buttons are sharing the same `model` Object as it's essentially a JS Object which is passed by reference. Hence the behavior.

Comment: @SiddAjmera Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have understood your requirement. Your html can be modified as

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>

<div *ngIf="isChecked == false">
  Atleast one checkbox should be checked!
</div>
<form name="form" (ngSubmit)="addBookletForm.valid && addBooklet()" #addBookletForm="ngForm" novalidate >
  <label *ngFor="let option of levelCheckboxes">
     <input name="booklet_level" [(ngModel)]="option.checked" type="checkbox" (change)="isCheckBoxChecked()">
    {{option.name}}
  </label>
</form>
```

And in your .ts file you can have a function called isCheckBoxChecked() to display the respective validation error,

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  isChecked: boolean = false;
  name = 'Angular';
  levelCheckboxes = [
        { name:'one', value:'1', checked:false },
        { name:'two', value:'2', checked:false },
        { name:'three', value:'3', checked:false }
    ]

  isCheckBoxChecked(){
    this.isChecked = false;
    this.levelCheckboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
      if(checkbox.checked){
        this.isChecked = true;
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: No, at least one checkbox must be checked.

Comment: @Vahid Thanks for the clarification ! let me correct the condition and will update the answer

Comment: You can test your solution in stackblitz (link in the question)

Comment: @Vahid I have made changes to the code and it is working based upon your requirements! Hope it helps

Comment: It seems this is the only way to check it manually. But still wondering why this happens. Btw, thanks.

Comment: Happy to help! :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are using the same value for the name attribute on every checkbox input, `booklet_level`. Because you are using an `ngForm` all the `NgModels` get merged to one. So, you get very weird and unexpected behaviour.

If you change the name to something like this, it will work:

```
<input name="booklet_level_{{option.name}}" required 
       type="checkbox" value="{{option.value}}" 
       [(ngModel)]="option.checked" #booklet_level="ngModel">
```

Comment: In this case, all the checkboxes must be checked.

Comment: @VahidNajafi well you are putting a `required` attribute on every checkbox. If you just want at least one to be selected you should not use the `required` attribute at all

Comment: In that case user can skip checkboxes without any selection. Would you please see the `stackblitz` demo provided in the question?